# Entry point (_main) undefined. for architecture arm64 error in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I keep getting "Entry point (_main) undefined. for architecture arm64" error and I don't know why? The code was working but then it decided to just give up on me.

I am on Xcode 13.3 building for iPhone

I know there are similar questions but they haven't helped me find the answer to my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add @main on above class AppDelegate.

Comment: I can't find app delegate, I have google it but that hasn't helped. where is it? thx

Comment: I think you might have deleted it?. You can create new project copy paste that file to this project